# Some tricky issue with chapter in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Again I'm asking for help, for a tricky issue, as for me.

It is demanded from me that in the TOC I must write chapter-level headings without page number and dot filling.

So, I'm using **tocloft** package to manage my ToC. And I used the following command to fullfill the demands:

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
```

BUT =) I need my bibliography to be included in ToC as a chapter-level heading, but with the page number. I am using the bibtex to manage my bibliography.

I wrote the following code, that to my opinion should work:

```
\cftpagenumberson{chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Библиографический список}
\bibliographystyle{gost71u2003}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{GSTBib}
```

I thought that it would turn the page numbers on for the chapter-level, but it did not. It has no page number aligned to the right.

How can I manage this issue?

Comment: Are youusing KOMA? If so, just add `\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}`

Comment: No, I'm not. Is there another way, without KOMA?

Comment: Mario, I've just tried your example. Here is the result: http://clip2net.com/s/6g3mS5. The trick did not work =(

Comment: I'm sorry, this is beyond me.  With KOMA is very easy to just set it so both the bibliography and the chapters have numbers and dots... but since your specs require no numbers for chapters I guess your approach would be the "logical" one.  However, I'm not familiar enough with `tocloft` to play with it and find a solution.  Perhaps using a `\phantomsection` before the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Библиографический список}` ?

Comment: Try `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}` first and `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}` later.

Comment: Ok, then. I tried to use  this: `\addcontentsline{toc}{}{Библиографический список}`, without defining the style, so I'm to write it manully. Is there a way to say TeX to put the dotted line and align pagenumber to the right? (Decause without the style, pagenumber is sticked right to the left, almost meshing uo with the label.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to do it should be to use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
```

instead of

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
```

and

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
```

instead of

```
\cftpagenumberson{chapter}
```

In fact, the following MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}

\chapter{Способы описания систем}

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Библиографический список}
\bibliographystyle{gost71u2003}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{GSTBib}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Uhm, I used `\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}` in my package, to make all chapters act the same. Adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}` just before the biblio works too.